# I am trying to get my error messages display if requirements are not met .For reason beyond my expertise I am getting an error and have no idea why

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

Im trying to get the error messages pushed into the empty array along with adding the showErrors function which should add the array to an li element within my html page and display it after i add the class of .show.
Or if you have a way you feel is better that could get this task completed feel free to share .Thanks you in advanced

```js
let terms = document.getElementById('terms')
const username = document.getElementById('username')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
let errorList = document.getElementById('error-list')
let errorContainer = document.getElementById('error')
const errorMessages = []

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (username.value.length < 5) {
    errorMessages.push('Username must be more than 5 characters');
  }

  if (password.value.length < 5) {
    errorMessages.push('Password must be more than 5 characters');
  }

  if (errorMessages.length > 0) {
    showErrors(errorMessages);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})

function showErrors(errorMessages) {
  errorMessages.forEach((errorMessage) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = errorMessage;
    errorList.appendChild(li);
  })
  errorContainer.classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

.error {
  display: none;
}

.error .show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <!--start of the form -->
      <form action="" id="form">
        <!-- Error Container-->
        <div id="error" class="error">
          <ul id="error-list" class="error-list"></ul>
        </div>
        <!-- inputs below-->
        <div>
          <input required type="text" id="username" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input required type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="terms">Terms & Conditions</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" />
        </div>
        <!--submit button-->
        <button type="submit" id="button">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, like the error message says, `errorMessages.foreach` is not a function. JS is case-sensitive, you need `forEach`.